# How to run tests for a specific Kibana plugin

Tags: node.js, angular, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to run unit tests for a Kibana plugin. I followed the example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/development-plugin-functional-tests.html) and made a config containing the location of the unit tests for the plugin. What I haven't been able to find is clear documentation on how to actually run unit tests for individual kibana plugin.

I know I could run the unit tests using Node but the packages the unit tests require use the 'import' function which isn't supported in Node. I'd like to know if there is an alternate solution other than refactoring the project to use require instead of import.

I'm pretty new to developing kibana plugins (and front-end development for that matter) so I'm not familiar with its testing capabilities.